# Redirection from Servlet/Filter does not work

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a problem with redirection - it simply does not work for valid paths.
Right now I use page forwarding in the Servlet, but I need redirection in a filter.

All the pages reside in the 'pages' folder and have a .jspx extension

I've tried the following (this path works with forwarding):

```
httpResponse.sendRedirect("/pages/login.jspx");
```

browser url is `http://[localhost]/pages/login.jspx`, and it shows Tomcat's 404 page, the context path (in my case it's '/hotel') is missing from the url, so, if I add it:

```
httpResponse.sendRedirect("/hotel/pages/login.jspx");
```

redirect does not happen, browser url does not change, and I'm shown the browser's 404 page (This program cannot display the webpage).

What am I doing wrong?

The filter which is used to test this has the following mapping:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "SecurityFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirected URL is indeed relative to the initially requested URL. To dynamically prepend the context path it's recommended to use `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()` instead of hardcoding it, because the context path value can be changed externally by server-specific configuration.

As to your concrete problem, I'm not sure if I understand "browser's 404 page" properly, perhaps you mean the browser-default error page which can occur when the server is unreachable or when the request has been redirected in an infinite loop (that should however have been made clear in the actual message of the browser default error page, at least Chrome and Firefox do that).

Given that your filter is mapped on `/*`, it's actually redirecting in an infinite loop because the request URL of the login page in turn also matches the URL pattern of the filter.

You'd need *either* to put the filter on a more specific URL pattern which does **not** cover the login page, e.g. on `/secured/*` where all restricted pages are been moved in there (or map it on `/pages/*` and put the login page outside there), *or* to fix your filter as follows:

```
String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/pages/login.jspx";

if (needsToRedirect && !request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL)) {
    response.sendRedirect(loginURL);
}
else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: That was indeed a redirect loop, I should have used a logger for this filter in the first place.

Comment: You're welcome. Using a real webbrowser and actually reading its error message (which should have said something like "this site isn't properly redirecting" or so) would also have brought lot of insight :)

Answer (score 1):

1 - Have you got logging or some other observable event in your servlet code that confirms it's definitely running?

2 - Redirects can fail if you write any actual response content *prior to* the redirect - have you anything doing that?

3 - Another option, set up a page in the root directory, even a "hello.html" static page, and see if you can redirect to that using either of "/hello.html" and "hello.html".

Just some ideas I would use in my own debug approach, hope something helps!